# opencv find centre of face in facedetction

Tags: python, opencv

I need to find the centre of a rectangle that gets put around a face when it's detected in OpenCV. I am using Python in Visual Studio.

Here is the code I am running:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from cv2 import *

import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cvtColor(frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )


    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    font = FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    # Draw text on the frame    
    putText(frame, 'Hayden' ,(10,100), font, 2,(255,255,255),2,LINE_AA)

    # Display the resulting frame
    imshow('Video', frame)


    if waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
destroyAllWindows()
```

---

All I want to do is find the centre of the rectangle, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry but I don't know python. The code for this in C++ is:

```
Point center = Point(rectangle.x + rectangle.width)/2, (rectangle.y + rectangle.height)/2);
```

I'd be surprised if this didn't translate almost exactly to python

Comment: Thanks, i tired changing it for use in python to this:
 pointCentre = Point(rectangle.x + rectangle.width)/2, (rectangle.y + rectangle.height)/2
Now it saying ''point is not defined'' So i assume that this function is for C++ only

Comment: I think there is one function for python like : cv.cvPoint(). I am not sure but check it once.

Comment: I tried cv.cvPoint() but there is no function for that either.
Anything else that i can try?

Answer (score 0):

The cv2.CascadeClassifier returns an two dimensional array, with a row for every discovered item. The coulmns (x, y, w, h) specify the bounding box of the discovered item. Hence, the center point is given by:

```
center = np.round((x+w/2, y+h/2)).astype("int32")
```

Here is a full MWE:

```
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np

img_data = requests.get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png").content
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(img_data), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1)

face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier( cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
roi = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY), 
                                    scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(40, 40))
for (x, y, w, h) in roi:
    center = np.round((x+w/2, y+h/2)).astype("int32")
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), color=(0,255,0))
    cv2.circle(img, center, radius=2, color=(0,255,0), thickness=-1)

cv2.imshow('Lenna', img)
if cv2.waitKey() & 0xff == 27: quit()
```